# simple questions about PyGTK, GTKbuilder, GTK+

Tags: python, user-interface, pygtk, glade, gtkbuilder

Okay, I'm just starting to get into creating GUIs with python and I'm a bit confused as how how I should go forward:

1. Should I download PyGTK or the current version of GTK+ if I'm using Python or does it matter?
2. Concerning GUI builders, from what people are saying, it seems like GTKbuilder is better to use than Glade because it's built into GTK+?  Is GTKbuilder also included in PyGTK or would I have to use Glade with PyGTK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyGTK bridges GTK+ to Python, so you need all three.

Glade is an application to edit XML files. You'll definitely want it. To read those files you can use either libglade (separate, deprecated) or GtkBuilder (built into GTK+, and therefore PyGTK).

Comment: You also might consider reviewing the Python Wiki's page devoted to GUI programming, as it enumerates the plethora of available GUI frameworks available for python:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming